# 301 редирект с html | php | aspx

Tags: apache, .htaccess, редирект, mod-rewrite

Необходимо настроить 301 редирект со всеми подстановками плана `index.html` `index.php` `index.aspx` на `/`, т.е. на вышестоящую категорию.
Например:

- `http://site.ru/index.html --> 301 --> http://site.ru/`
- `http://site.ru/catalog/index.html --> http://site.ru/catalog/`
- `http://site.ru/catalog.html --> http://site.ru/catalog/`

Добавил такую конкструкцию в .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/

RewriteRule ^index\.php$  http://site.ru/ [R=301,L]
```

но не помогло, редиректит только главная, а внутренние не редиректят.

Буду благодарен кто подскажет. ну или хотя бы в какую сторону смотреть.
Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>про catalog.html непонятно, в регексп не добавил</strike>

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[A-Z]{3,9}\ (\S*?/)index\.(?:php|html|aspx)"
RewriteRule "^" "http://site.ru%1" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "^(.+?)\.\w{3,4}$"
RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%1" -d
RewriteRule "\.(?:php|html|aspx)$" "http://site.ru%1/" [R=301,L]
```

<strike>По каталогу нужно словить две подмаски (пути без расширения): 1-ый в `RewriteRule` берём для редиректа, а подмаску в `RewriteCond` берём для проверки, что этот путь есть директория. Исходя из того, что `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` в контексте htaccess содержит полный путь в файловой системе.</strike>

Comment: про данный пример http: //site.ru/catalog.html --> http: //site.ru/catalog / я имел ввиду, что если будет обращение к файлу, котороый по сути является каталогом, то произойдет перенаправление на каталог т.е. на конечный слэш

Comment: Редирект сработал на ура) Спасибо. Может для уникального случая, что идет выше в коментарии тоже подскажите

Comment: @okseo обновил пост

Comment: Доброго утра! Работает только первое перенаправление, а этот  http: //site.ru/catalog.html --> http: //site.ru/catalog /  нет - отдает 404 ошибку, т.к. не находит файла. вот потому и хочу что бы сработал именно редирект

Comment: @okseo htaccess где лежит, в корне или выше? Для корня это 100% рабочий вариант. Если выше, то теряется часть пути.

Comment: нет, полный путь к htsccess такой ../www/site/.htaccess

Comment: @okseo обновил, но это сомнительно с точки зрения нагрузки на сервер.

Comment: проверил не работает. все та же 404. работает только редирект с index.html|php|asp ((

Comment: @okseo ошибок нет, всё проверено. 301 редирект кэшируется браузером, так что он может старый редирект отдавать.

Comment: да не должен, я такие изменение через ctrl f5 проверяю на странице... А если все верно, может подскажите. почему так может быть?.. может не совсем в тему, но настройка редиректа с https на http тоже 404 отдает (там тоже не мало вариантов перепробовал)

Comment: @okseo ф5 не поможет, 301 редирект сохраняется на какое-то время (permanent же). Для тестов лучше изначально 303 делать. Используйте f12 или firebug для отключения кэша, там вроде галочка есть.